# Populating JSON data from API in Python pandas DataFrame - TypeError and IndexError

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I am trying to populate a pandas DataFrame with select information from JSON output fetched from an API.

```py
candidate_list = []

for candidate in candidate_response['data']:
    if 'error' not in candidate_response:
       candidate_list.append([candidate['id'], candidate['attributes']['first_name'], candidate['attributes']
       ['last_name'], candidate['relationships']['educations']['data']['id']])
```

The DataFrame populates fine until I add `candidate['relationships']['educations']['data']['id']`, which throws `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

When trying to get the values of the indexes for `['id']` by using `candidate['relationships']['educations']['data'][0]['id']` instead, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

The JSON output looks something like:

```
"data": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "first_name": "Tester",
            "last_name": "Testman",
            "other stuff": "stuff",
        },
        "id": "732887",
        "relationships": {
            "educations": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "605372",
                        "type": "educations"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "605371",
                        "type": "educations"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "605370",
                        "type": "educations"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

How would I go about successfully filling a column in the DataFrame with the 'id's under 'relationships'>'educations'>'data'?

Comment: can you create it using the pandas read json function? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note then when using `candidate['relationships']['educations']['data']['id']` you get that error because at `data` there is a list, and not a dictionary. And you cannot access dictionary by name.

Assuming, what you are trying to achieve is one entry per `data.attributes.relationships.educations.data` entry. Complete code that works and does what you are trying is:

```
import json

json_string = """{
    "data": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "Tester",
                "last_name": "Testman",
                "other stuff": "stuff"
            },
            "id": "732887",
            "relationships": {
                "educations": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": "605372",
                            "type": "educations"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "605371",
                            "type": "educations"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "605370",
                            "type": "educations"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}"""

candidate_response = json.loads(json_string)

candidate_list = []

for candidate in candidate_response['data']:
    if 'error' not in candidate_response:
        for data in candidate['relationships']['educations']['data']:
            candidate_list.append(
                [
                    candidate['id'], 
                    candidate['attributes']['first_name'], 
                    candidate['attributes']['last_name'], 
                    data['id']
                ]
            )

print(candidate_list)
```

Code run available at [ideone](https://ideone.com/rsxLs3).

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed your code and also ran it on Jupyter notebook all looks good, I am getting the output,
The error you got `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, that is because you were not using the index, this required because the value which you are looking for that is in the list.

and about this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Maybe some code typo mistake is done from your side otherwise the code is fine.

here is the output of your following code:

```
candidate_list = []

for candidate in candidate_response['data']:
    if 'error' not in candidate_response:
        candidate_list.append([candidate['id'], candidate['attributes']['first_name'], candidate['attributes']['last_name'],candidate['relationships']['educations']['data'][0]['id']])
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I've double checked and that code was copied and pasted, still getting the index error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

probably for any candidate candidate['relationships']['educations']['data'] is an empty list